# Taylor Series and Fourier Series

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Taylor series expansion of function, f, is a vector in the vector space with basis: {(x-a)^0, (x-a)^1, (x-a)^3, ..., (x-a)^n, ...}. This vector space has a countably infinite dimension. When f is expressed as linear combination of the basis vector the scalar multiple for the n-th basis vector is Diff_n{f}(a)/n!

Fourier series expansion of function, f, is a vector in the vector space with basis: {sin(1x), cos(1x), sin(2x), cos(2x), ..., sin(nx), cos(nx), ...}. This vector space has a countably infinite dimension. When f is expressed as linear combination of the basis vector the scalar multiple for the n-th basis vectors are Int{f.sin(nx)} and Int{f.cos(nx)}.

Questions:

1. The vector space for the Fourier series has an inner product, Int{f.g}, and it's this inner product that provides the above expressions like Int{f.sin(nx)} and Int{f.cos(nx)}. Is there a similar inner product based derivation of the scalar multiples for the vector space of spanned by the polynomial basis in Taylor series?
2. What is the relationship, if any, between the vector space produced by Taylor Series and that of Fourier Series? E.g. is one a subspace of the other?
3. When Fourier series is taught, why isn't Taylor Series re-explained in the vector space framework used for Fourier series? And would this approach not lead the discussion of the implication of the choice of basis (and perhaps the choice of inner product) for function spaces?
4. Just as Fourier series get generalized to Fourier Transform (the summation of the series becomes an integral), is there something equivalent to Taylor series?
5. Are there any recommended resources (books, courses, etc.) available which can help clarify my thinking regarding these issues?

Comment: These are nice questions but not quite appropriate for MO; I'm sure they would be well-received on math.stackexchange.com. 

Comment: Yes, very interesting questions, but better for Math Stack Exchange, than here.

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure (yet) that this needs to be rapidly shunted over to MSE. There is something lurking in the background about representation of differential operators on certain function spaces with respect to certain bases... although perhaps I am reading more into the question than the OP intended

Comment: Unless you are only interested in a purely formal framework, you need to be careful with your description of these spaces. For example, not every power series is meaningful (i.e., has positive radius of convergence), and even if it is, it need not equal the function it comes from, etc.

Comment: Also, a convergent Taylor (or even Laurent) series for $f(x)$ 
in powers of $(x-a)$ *is* a special case of a Fourier series
(using complex exponentials in place of sines and cosines), 
namely for the restriction of $f$ to any circle centered at $a$
on which the series converges.

Comment: The space of formal power series is not countable dimensional: It is (isomorphic) to the space of *all* scalar sequences which has dimension $c$ (cardinality of the continuum). The system $\lbrace (x-a)^0, (x-a)^1,\ldots\rbrace$ is a basis for the space of all polynomials.


Answer (score 2):

In your question you only discuss the formal analogy, disregarding the questions of convergence,
and what exactly a "function" is. This is a reasonable setting indeed, if one restricts oneself to
finite sums. Then there is an exact correspondence, if we extend the set of Taylor series to Laurent
series. Finite Laurent series $\sum a_n z^n$ are in one-to one correspondence with
finite trigonometric sums $\sum a_n\exp(int)$. (These are essentially the same as the series in
sines and cosines). The subspace of polynomials consists of those sums for which $n\geq 0$.
One can give a condition on the series of sines and cosines to correspond to a Laurent series
with $n\geq 0$.
If one wants to pass to infinite sums, one has to use some topology.
The simplest case is when the topology is defined by the standard scalar product. Completion of the
space of polynomials in this topology gives the space $H_2$ which can be thought of as a space
of trigonometric (Fourier) series, and as a space of Power series. And for the coefficients of
the expansion you have two formulas: one involving integration, another differentiation.
These formulas give the same result in view of Cauchy formula.

On your other questions. Fourier series are generalized to Fourier transform.
Taylor series are similarly generalized to Laplace transform. 
(With an intermediate step of Dirichlet series).

For recommended reading... there are a lot of books, the appropriate one depends on your prerequisites.
Hoffman's book Banach Spaces of Analytic Functions begins with a very clear explanation
of relations
between Taylor and Fourier series.